# Check generic type before casting at runtime

Tags: java, generics, casting

We were given the task to create an object structure for evaluating expressions (e.g. "1 + 2" or "true & false"). The parser is provided, as well as a factory interface to create the expression objects.

We use generics for the different expressions: `Expression<Integer>` returns an Integer, `Expression<Boolean>` returns a Boolean, etc.

The problem we're facing is that the provided interface uses the raw type `Expression`, for example:

```
public Expression createSumExpression(Expression left, Expression right);
```

The sum expression is only defined when the operands are of type `Expression<Integer>` or `Expression<Double>`. How can we check this? 
Due to type erasure, the type information is not available at run time, and it just results in a `ClassCastException` if it's incorrect.

I can modify everything, except for the `createSumExpression` and `createAndExpression` functions.

---

This is a simplified piece of code that demonstrates the problem. It works, but it doesn't look very nice, and it gives multiple warnings.

#### Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expression<?> left1 = new BasicExpression<>(42);
        Expression<?> right1 = new BasicExpression<>(3);        
        Expression<?> sum = createSumExpression(left1, right1);
        System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n",left1.getValue(), right1.getValue(), sum.getValue());

        Expression<?> left2 = new BasicExpression<>(true);
        Expression<?> right2 = new BasicExpression<>(false);
        Expression<?> and = createAndExpression(left2, right2);
        System.out.printf("%b & %b = %b%n",left2.getValue(), right2.getValue(), and.getValue());
    }

    private static Expression createSumExpression(Expression left, Expression right) { // Raw types because of given interface
        return new BinaryExpression<Integer,Expression<Integer>,Expression<Integer>>(left, right) {
            @Override
            protected Integer operation(Expression<Integer> left, Expression<Integer> right) {
                return left.getValue() + right.getValue();
            }
        };
    }

    private static Expression createAndExpression(Expression left, Expression right) { // Raw types because of given interface
        return new BinaryExpression<Boolean,Expression<Boolean>,Expression<Boolean>>(left, right) {
            @Override
            protected Boolean operation(Expression<Boolean> left, Expression<Boolean> right) {
                return left.getValue() & right.getValue();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

#### Expression.java

```
abstract public class Expression<V> {
    public abstract V getValue();
}
```

#### BasicExpression.java

```
public class BasicExpression<V> extends Expression<V> {
    public BasicExpression(V value) {
        this.value = value; 
    }
    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    private V value;
}
```

#### BinaryExpression.java

```
abstract public class BinaryExpression<V, L, R> extends Expression<V> {
    public BinaryExpression (L l, R r) {
        this.left = l;
        this.right = r;
    }
    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return operation(left, right);
    }
    abstract protected V operation(L left, R right);

    private L left;
    private R right;
}
```

---

The provided interface is:

```
/**
 * @param <E>
 *            Your class for representing an expression.
 */
public interface IExpressionFactory<E> {
    public E createSumExpression(E left, E right) throws ModelException;
    public E createAndExpression(E left, E right) throws ModelException;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you modify `Expression` itself?

Comment: @JornVernee Yes, I can modify `Expression`.

Comment: IMO, it's conception issue of the interface signature. If `createSumExpression` accepts only `Integer` and `Double`, the signature of the method should be `public Expression createSumExpression(Expression<? extends Number> left, Expression<? extends Number> right);` to prevent any exception. And as you can't modify it, there's no *"clear"* solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are not really useful in this case, since most of the types will be derived from an input string at run time, and generics are a compile time thing. There is no way to know the types ahead of time any ways. It's only really useful in a simple example like this.

So my suggestion is to discard the generics and implement your own dynamic type system. For instance something like:

```
enum Type {
    Integer,
    Boolean;
}

class ScriptObject {
    private final Object value;
    private final Type type;

    private ScriptObject(Object value, Type type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static ScriptObject of(boolean b) {
        return new ScriptObject(b, Type.Boolean);
    }

    public static ScriptObject of(int i) {
        return new ScriptObject(i, Type.Integer);
    }

    public int asInt() {
        return (int) value;
    }

    public boolean asBoolean() {
        return (boolean) value;
    }

    public static boolean areType(Type type, ScriptObject...objects) {
        for(ScriptObject o : objects) {
            if(o.type != type)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }

}

abstract class Expression {
    public abstract ScriptObject getValue();
}

class BasicExpression extends Expression {
    private final ScriptObject value;

    public BasicExpression(ScriptObject value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public ScriptObject getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}

abstract class BinaryExpression extends Expression {
    private final Expression left;
    private final Expression right;

    public BinaryExpression (Expression l, Expression r) {
        this.left = l;
        this.right = r;
    }

    @Override
    public ScriptObject getValue() {        
        return operation(left.getValue(), right.getValue());
    }

    protected abstract ScriptObject operation(ScriptObject left, ScriptObject right);

}
```

Converting your example will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Expression left1 = new BasicExpression(ScriptObject.of(42));
    Expression right1 = new BasicExpression(ScriptObject.of(3));     
    Expression sum = createSumExpression(left1, right1);
    System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s%n",left1.getValue(), right1.getValue(), sum.getValue());

    Expression left2 = new BasicExpression(ScriptObject.of(true));
    Expression right2 = new BasicExpression(ScriptObject.of(false));
    Expression and = createAndExpression(left2, right2);
    System.out.printf("%s && %s = %s%n",left2.getValue(), right2.getValue(), and.getValue());

    createAndExpression(left1, right2).getValue(); // fails with: Can not apply '&' to '42' and 'false' 
}

private static Expression createSumExpression(Expression left, Expression right) {
    return new BinaryExpression(left, right) {
        @Override
        protected ScriptObject operation(ScriptObject left, ScriptObject right) {
            if(!ScriptObject.areType(Type.Integer, left, right)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can not apply '+' to '" + left + "' and '" + right + "'");
            }
            return ScriptObject.of(left.asInt() + right.asInt());
        }
    };
}

private static Expression createAndExpression(Expression left, Expression right) {
    return new BinaryExpression(left, right) {
        @Override
        protected ScriptObject operation(ScriptObject left, ScriptObject right) {
            if(!ScriptObject.areType(Type.Boolean, left, right)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can not apply '&' to '" + left + "' and '" + right + "'");
            }
            return ScriptObject.of(left.asBoolean() && right.asBoolean());
        }
    };
}
```

I've tried to keep the example simple, but some notes are that you probably want to create a bunch of helper functions for the type checks and also use a custom exception type, probably a checked one that you then catch and output it's message somewhere, instead of just crashing.

You have to do the type checks yourself, which is more work, but the advantage is that you can totally decide when (and even if) you check the types, and what kind of error message to supply.

There is also still room to create a conversion mechanism for types, so instead of just checking that the type is what you want, you could try to convert it to the desired type, which is not a feature (besides auto-(un)boxing) of Java's type system.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather have compile-time type-safety without checking for exceptions due to possible runtime failures, you could also define multiple factories.

Exceptions can still be thrown if calling an invalid method for a certain type, but you can't create an expression of the wrong types.

For example, you could have an `ExpressionFactory` which handles only `Integer` expressions.

```
private static class IntegerExpressionFactory implements IExpressionFactory<Expression<Integer>> {

    @Override
    public Expression<Integer> createSumExpression(Expression<Integer> left, Expression<Integer> right) {
        return new BinaryExpression<>(left, right) {
            @Override
            protected Integer operation(Expression<Integer> left, Expression<Integer> right) {
                return left.getValue() + right.getValue();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Expression<Integer> createAndExpression(Expression<Integer> left, Expression<Integer> right) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't perform AND operation on integer expressions.");
    }
}
```

It will have the following effect on your existing code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntegerExpressionFactory integerExpressionFactory = new IntegerExpressionFactory();
    Expression<Integer> left1 = new BasicExpression<>(42);
    Expression<Integer> right1 = new BasicExpression<>(3);
    Expression<Integer> sum = integerExpressionFactory.createSumExpression(left1, right1);
    System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", left1.getValue(), right1.getValue(), sum.getValue()); // 42 + 3 = 45

    integerExpressionFactory.createAndExpression(left1, right1); // UnsupportedOperationException

    Expression<Boolean> left2 = new BasicExpression<>(true);
    Expression<Boolean> right2 = new BasicExpression<>(false);
    integerExpressionFactory.createAndExpression(left2, right2); // Does not compile
}
```

It's less flexible than a custom typing system in which you can combine operations of multiple types, but it's a more straightforward implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Because you cannot access that information at run time there is no way to definitively know what the type of the generic is without lots of try/catch blocks which is really ugly. So instead add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` the line before the method signatures and make sure you sanitize your input.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Expression createSumExpression(Expression left, Expression right) { // Raw types because of given interface
    return new BinaryExpression<Integer,Expression<Integer>,Expression<Integer>>(left, right) {
        @Override
        protected Integer operation(Expression<Integer> left, Expression<Integer> right) {
            return left.getValue() + right.getValue();
        }
    };
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Expression createAndExpression(Expression left, Expression right) { // Raw types because of given interface
    return new BinaryExpression<Boolean,Expression<Boolean>,Expression<Boolean>>(left, right) {
        @Override
        protected Boolean operation(Expression<Boolean> left, Expression<Boolean> right) {
            return left.getValue() & right.getValue();
        }
    };
}
```

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` will tell the java compiler to not worry about the unchecked casting and continue compiling.

Sanitize your input so that only `Expression<Integer>` and `Expression<Double>` are used with `createSumExpression()` only. and the same goes for the `boolean` side of the expressions

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, since we have no control over how `createSumExpression()` is called.

Comment: This won't solve runtime exception `ClassCastException`. I don't see the point.

Comment: The way to solve the class cast exception is to never run into it in the first place. If you are never trying to add booleans or bitwise operate on integers you won't run into the `ClassCastExeption`. If you only feed the "create methods" the data they want then you are fine. If you really wanted to you can try and cast the variable inside a try/catch block but then you still have mismatched classes.